# Python Counter Solution for Anagrams much Slower than Sorting Solution - why?

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, sorting, hashtable

I made two versions of an algorithm to find anagrams of a given word within a language reference. I would have expected the `Counter` version to be faster, as `Counter` is hash table based (O(1) access), whereas sorting is generally O(n log n), as I understand. Yet the sorting version seems to be about 60x faster. Can anyone please explain why?

Sorting version:

```
import urllib.request
import time

LANGUAGE_REFERENCE_URL = "https://inventwithpython.com/dictionary.txt"


def find_anagrams_sorting(input_str):
    input_str = input_str.upper()
    sorted_input_str = "".join(sorted(input_str))
    results = []
    for idx, word in enumerate(sorted_words_list):
        if word == sorted_input_str:
            results.append(words_list[idx])
    return results


with urllib.request.urlopen(LANGUAGE_REFERENCE_URL) as response:
    words_list = response.read().decode('utf-8').split("\n")

words_list = list(map(lambda x: x.upper(), words_list))  # Needed if source has mixed case
sorted_words_list = list(map(lambda x: "".join(sorted(x)), words_list))

# Time execution for sorting version
start = time.perf_counter()
print(find_anagrams_sorting("rats"))
print(find_anagrams_sorting("RatS"))
print(find_anagrams_sorting("Goldfish"))
print(find_anagrams_sorting("SteaL"))
end = time.perf_counter()
print(f"Checked all anagrams in language reference using sorting. Seconds taken: {end - start:.7f}")
```

Counter version:

```
import urllib.request
import time
from collections import Counter

LANGUAGE_REFERENCE_URL = "https://inventwithpython.com/dictionary.txt"


def find_anagrams_hash_table(input_str):
    input_str = input_str.upper()
    input_str_counter = Counter(input_str)
    results = []
    for idx, word in enumerate(word_counters):
        if Counter(word) == input_str_counter:
            results.append(words_list[idx])
    return results


with urllib.request.urlopen(LANGUAGE_REFERENCE_URL) as response:
    words_list = response.read().decode('utf-8').split("\n")

words_list = list(map(lambda x: x.upper(), words_list))  # Needed if source has mixed case
word_counters = list(map(lambda x: Counter(x), words_list))

# Time execution for hash table version
start = time.perf_counter()
print(find_anagrams_hash_table("rats"))
print(find_anagrams_hash_table("RatS"))
print(find_anagrams_hash_table("Goldfish"))
print(find_anagrams_hash_table("SteaL"))
end = time.perf_counter()
print(f"Checked all anagrams in language reference using hash table. Seconds taken: {end - start:.7f}")
```

Comment: For such small words `n log n`  is so small that anything else can quite simply drag down the runtime. Profiling where the time is spent and much lrger test-inputs might give a hind during profiling.

Comment: I can't explain your findings but I can say that you should be using a dictionary for this and it will be **much** faster

Comment: @Cobra Interesting. The reason a dictionary didn't occur to me is that there are no explicit keys. Are you saying that accessing a list is much slower than using arbitrary keys just so the words can be stored in a dictionary?

Comment: Comparing a counter object involves comparing string keys and their number, and corresponding integer values. This seems more complex than just comparing strings.

Comment: @RobinAndrews With a dictionary, you would use the sorted word as a key. The associated value would be a list of words that are made up of the key. As the dictionary keys are hashed, looking them up would be very fast when compared to iterating over a list. I'll write an answer that shows how I would approach the problem

Comment: In your counter-based solution, you precompute `word_counters = list(map(lambda x: Counter(x), words_list))`, so now you have a list of Counters. Cool. Then, for each query, you do this: `for idx, word in enumerate(word_counters)` `if Counter(word)...`. But `word_counter` is a list of Counters, no? So `word` is already a Counter and `Counter(word)` is a very expensive and unnecessary copy operation. That doesn't explain a 60x factor but it is certainly significant.

Comment: By the way, you could use a simpler `map` invocation to create that list: `word_counters = list(map(Counter, word_list))`.

Comment: @rici Awesome. Your improved version gives Seconds taken: 0.1918549 as against Seconds taken: 0.5463342 for the original counter version. A bit more than twice as good I think.

Answer (score 0):

Build a dictionary where the keys are sorted words and the associated values are lists of words that can be made up of the key.

The lookup in the dictionary will be optimum due to the nature of hashed keys.

```
import requests
from collections import defaultdict
from functools import cache

LANGUAGE_REFERENCE_URL = 'https://inventwithpython.com/dictionary.txt'

class Anagram:
    def __init__(self):
        self._wd = None

    @staticmethod
    @cache
    def make_key(word):
        return tuple(sorted(word.upper()))

    @property
    def wd(self):
        if self._wd is None:
            (r := requests.get(LANGUAGE_REFERENCE_URL, stream=True)).raise_for_status()
            self._wd = defaultdict(list)
            for word in map(bytes.decode, r.iter_lines()):
                self._wd[self.__class__.make_key(word)].append(word.upper())
        return self._wd
    def find(self, word):
        if words := self.wd.get(self.__class__.make_key(word)):
            return words[:]


anagram = Anagram()

print(anagram.find('Horse'))
print(anagram.find('steal'))
print(anagram.find('veto'))
print(anagram.find('veto'))
print(anagram.find('pluto'))
print(anagram.find('ppp'))
```

**Output:**

```
['HORSE', 'SHORE']
['LEAST', 'SLATE', 'STALE', 'STEAL', 'TALES']
['VETO', 'VOTE']
['VETO', 'VOTE']
['PLUTO']
None
```

Comment: Thanks. That's a couple of orders of magnitude faster I think. One small bug I can't quite see how to fix : if you search for the same item more than once you get `ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list`.

Comment: That's weird. I just checked again and got `Seconds taken: 0.7073993` for the four words you used. Tried several times and got similar results to my version based on counters. Not sure why just that one time it came out so fast, unless I mistook an 8 for a 0. I thought it was something like 0.0006 seconds. I'd be curious to know how the versions compare for you.

Comment: @RobinAndrews When the code looks for the first word, it takes time to download the file and set up the dictionary (lazy loading). Subsequent lookups are all in-memory. So, the time taken to look up 'Horse' includes the time needed to download the file and build the dictionary. Subsequent lookups will be significantly faster. The bug you identified could have been dealt with in a couple of ways. I chose to return a copy of the list of words that are anagrams of the word being checked. Thus the caller can safely (because it's a copy) remove the lookup word if required